# Separación de palabras espaciadas en máximo de 2 grupos

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

Estoy intentando realizar en python 3.6 una separación de un conjunto de palabras (todo lo que no sea espacios en blanco) de modo que quede una primera palabra en una variable y el resto, en una segunda.

El código que he planteado es:

```
a,b = input().split()
```

Ejecución:

Input: `prueba asdf`

Variables:

- `a` -- `prueba`
- `b` -- `asdf`

Pero cuando lo hago introduciendo más palabras, no funciona, me da un `ValueError`.

El código deseado sería de esta forma:

```
test = prueba asdf prueba2 PRUEBA3
a,b = test.split()
```

Variables:

- `a` -- `prueba`
- `b` -- `asdf prueba2 PRUEBA3`

¿De qué manera podría realizarlo para que el resultado fuera que en `a` se alojase `prueba` y el resto fuera dirigido a `b`?

Cosas que he sacado en claro hasta ahora

- Usar `split` con varias variables antes de la asignación limita a la cantidad de variables puestas. Eso quiere decir que si usas `a,b,c = stringtest.split()`, estás forzando a que sean 3 palabras las que encontrará.

Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Un pequeño detalle, en el primer ejemplo que pones, (a,b = input().split()) la variable "a" guardará el primer string que pongas y "b" el segundo. Solo puedes guardar en este caso dos valores, no 5 como propones.

Comment: ¡Ahá! Eso me suena más cercano. ¿Habrá alguna forma de hacer lo que comento? Porque si no es con split, me las estoy viendo y deseando...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con Pyton 3.x puedes, al asignar a una secuencia de variables una secuencia de datos, usar el operador `*` delante de una de las variables para designar que esa recibirá una secuencia con el resto de los datos.

Así que en tu caso:

```
a, *b = "1 2 3".split()
```

causaría que `a` recibiera la cadena `"1"`, mientras que `b` recibíra *la lista* `["2", "3"]`.

Esta respuesta por tanto no es equivalente a usar el parámetro `maxsplit=1`, pues en ese caso `split(maxsplit=1)` devolvería sólo dos elementos, dejando la subcadena `"2 3"` sin partir. Dependiendo de cómo siga tu programa puedes preferir usar `maxsplit` o el operador `*` sobre `b`.

Comment: ¿Eso sería una conversión indirecta a lista tras el split?
Había oído hablar de cosas así, pero no había visto un caso práctico

Comment: No exactamente... `split()` de hecho retorna una lista. Lo que hacemos en este caso es asignar una lista a una tupla de variables. Aquí el "truco" lo hace el operador de asignación,  y no `split()`. Es decir, esto también funciona: `a,*b = [1,2,3,4]`  y en ese caso `a` seria 1 y `b` sería `[2,3,4]`. En general la tupla de variables a la izda del `=` debería tener el mismo número de elementos que la lista al otro lado del `=`, pero gracias al `*`, una de las variables puede "absorber" el resto de elementos.

Answer (score 2):

Entiendo lo que dices, lo puedes hacer como comentan arriba,

```
text = "text1, text2, text3"
a, b = text.split(" ",1)
print (a)
print (b)
```

Resultado a: text1

Resultado b: text2, text3

Comment: Efectivamente, David, eso es justo lo que buscaba. He puesto otra solución que también he encontrado a través de Stack overflow en inglés.

Comment: No escribas mas de una respuesta.. por favor edita tu respuesta y agrega la nueva informacion alli.

Comment: @gbianchi Okei, elimino la respuesta incorrecta.

Answer (score 0):

Tras buscarlo en [so], he encontrado la siguiente [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50848764/split-string-into-two-parts-only), que traduciré a continuación:

Desde la [documentación oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

> **str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)**
>
> Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter
> string. If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are done (thus,
> the list will have at most maxsplit+1 elements). If maxsplit is not
> specified or -1, then there is no limit on the number of splits (all
> possible splits are made).

Así que realizando lo siguiente:

```
'1 2 3'.split(maxsplit=1)
```

Se obtiene como resultado

```
# ['1', '2 3']
```

Que es justo lo que andaba buscando.

Comment: Yep! Perfecto!!!